# CSS doesn't take effect on load?

Tags: html, css

I have some *CSS* that I've been trying to figure out and for some odd reasons, it doesn't like to take effect on load.

For example, this is how it appears directly after loading:
[image: Text and Icon On load]

Then if I go into inspect element and change 1 number's pixel it reverts to:
[image: Image after css change]

@Niet the Dark Absol's Solution:
[image: After applying width and height to icon]

Could this possibly be due to a hierarchy issue? As in it's not picking up the *CSS* because it's picking something else?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="additionals">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="fa fa-rocket"></div>
            Increase your efficiency.
        </li>
        <li>
            DonorPro = productivity. Say goodbye to hours of data entry, difficult mail merges, and paper pushing.
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.additionals ul {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 20px;
}

.additionals ul li {
    font-family: 'roboto',sans-serif;
    color: #111;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 400px;
}

.additionals .fa{
    color: #000!important;
    margin: 0 2px 0 0!important;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -37px;
    font-size: 33px;
    top: 27px;
    left: -6px;
}
```

**[JS FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/o470qcfx/)**

Comment: How do you insert your css file??

Comment: Through the `<head>` tag 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="....../DonorProHomepage.min.css">`

Comment: Creating a **JSFiddle** will more helpful for SO users to find the solution for you.

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay added fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, it causes from hierarchy. Depends on second image, you have to use two columns for it. One for icon and one for texts. I don't know why you use list for it but if you have to, you must do somrething like that:

```
<div class="additionals">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="fa fa-rocket"></div>
            <div class="li-content"> 
                <p class="content-title">Increase your efficiency.</p>
                <p class="content-text">DonorPro = productivity. Say goodbye to hours of data entry, difficult mail merges, and paper pushing. </p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.additionals ul {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 20px;
}

.additionals ul li {
    font-family: 'roboto',sans-serif;
    color: #111;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 400px;
}

//Clear for floated elements
.additionals ul li:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.additionals .fa{
    color: #000!important;
    width: 40px; //Choose any width you like.
    float: left; //Float icon to the left as a column
}

.additionals .li-content {
    width: 360px; // 400px - 40px(icon width)
    float: left; //Float content to left as a colum near of icon
}
```

Comment: This solved it, no idea why it's in `<ul>`, just the way it came across my desk. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take a guess that it's because the icon font hasn't loaded when the browser renders the page, and it doesn't recalculate flow when it does.

Try specifying a `width` and `height` for your icon element. This should reserve the space in the flow so that things float around it properly without you having to trigger a re-draw.

Comment: This does sound like it would work, however it just makes the spacing larger (will edit question with screenshot)

Comment: Odd. Definitely seems like a browser issue to me though. One thing I will say is that it is very wrong semantically for you to be using `ul`/`li` there. What you have is not a list, so you should not be marking it up as one. Perhaps if you used more appropriate tags, you would avoid the glitch altogether?

Comment: Edited the code to use all divs, still have the same result: http://jsfiddle.net/o470qcfx/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should define the icon on the UL block. No need for extra `div` elements:

HTML:

```
<div class="additionals">
    <ul class="fa fa-rocket" >
        <li>Increase your efficiency.</li>
        <li>DonorPro = productivity. Say goodbye to hours of data entry, difficult mail merges, and paper pushing.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.additionals ul {
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 20px;
}

.additionals ul li {
    font-family: 'roboto',sans-serif;
    color: #111;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
    width: 400px;
}
.additionals .fa::before {
    margin-left:-45px;
    float:left;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #000!important;
}
```

See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/auvo02yL/2/)